# Make a header file in embedded c

Tags: c, header, embedded, 8051

I am programming a 80c51 chip and I have a bucketload of functions as well as define statements. I am working with in the mcu 8051 ide. I want these functions and these defines in a separate header file but I don't know what I must type in the header file. currently I only have the defines and functions and that's it.

I also do not know how to include it when I put it in my application's folder. I simply use the include statement in my program,

```
#include <at89x51.h> // needed for the ucontroller
#include <communication_functions.h>
```

but it cannot find it. How do I tell the program to look for the .h in it's own folder?

Comment: `#include <communication_functions.h>`-> `#include "communication_functions.h"`

Comment: @MichaelWalz now I finally know when to use "" and <> for header files. I have wondered about this for years.

Comment: Sometimes reading the documentation can be useful.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to create a C header file(myheader.h) where you put your function's definition .And then,create a C file(myheader.c),where you are supposed to rewrite the function defined in the myheader.h file.Finally,use 
`#include "myheader.h"`         before you use your own function which is in the myheader.h file.

Comment: Witht eh exception of macros and `inline functions`, a header should **never** have definitions!